# Angular: ExpressionChangedAfterChecked in nested form with validators added by child

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I am trying to pass a form in Angular to a child components in Angular. Within the child component I am dynamically adding some controls to the form and using custom controls (children of the child component) with a ControlValueAccessor to display the form, which implement validators. However, I am getting an unexpected ExpressionChangedAfterChecked error due to the validity of the form changing.

I have drilled down the error to this minimal reproduction (which does not even use the custom ControlValueAccessors anymore nor adds the controls dynamically, so the error must lie somewhere else...).

**App.Component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <app-form-container [form]="form"></app-form-container>
    <button [disabled]="!valid">Button</button>`,
  styleUrls: []
})
export class AppComponent  {
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({child1: new FormControl(''), child2: new FormControl('value')});
  get valid(): boolean {
    return this.form.valid;
  }
}
```

**FormContainer.Component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-container',
  template: `
    <div [formGroup]="form">
      <input required formControlName="child1">
      <input required formControlName="child2">
    </div>`,
  styles: []
})
export class FormContainerComponent {
  @Input()
  form!: FormGroup;
}
```

This is the order in which the AppComponent is checked and when the error occurs:

```
app.component.ts:19 AppComponent ngDoCheck
app.component.ts:24 AppComponent valid true
app.component.ts:24 AppComponent valid false
main.ts:6  ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value for 'disabled': 'true'. Current value: 'false'. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0100
    at throwErrorIfNoChangesMode (core.mjs:8515:11)
    at bindingUpdated (core.mjs:12843:17)
    at Module.ɵɵproperty (core.mjs:13518:9)
    at AppComponent_Template (app.component.ts:8:13)
app.component.ts:19 AppComponent ngDoCheck
app.component.ts:24 AppComponent valid false
```

I have found a solution to the problem which is to simply do a `cdref.detectChanges` in the `OnInit` hook of the app component (and anywhere else where the form is replaced) but I feel like this is kinda "hacky" and there should be a nicer way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** If you need to set validators in child, you can use `setValidators` for the form control(s). Remember to also call `updateValueAndValidity`. Also do it after the view has been intialized, otherwise you will get the same error. So in child do:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.form.get('child1')?.setValidators(Validators.required);
  this.form.get('child1')?.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

[**UPDATED STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-kwkusk?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

If you are using a reactive form, you should set the validators to the formcontrols, never to the input itself. If you are using template driven forms, i.e `ngModel`, then use `required` on the input.

With this change you get rid of the error, as the validators are set immediately when form is created.

```
form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
  child1: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]), 
  child2: new FormControl('value', [Validators.required])
});
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-5magyz?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)**

Comment: Thanks! It is really helpful to know this is the source of the error. Is there potentially any way to keep using reactive forms but still only set the validators in the child components?

The code I provided is a simplified version of a rather big form and I wanted to avoid having the "logic of the child components" (e.g. what validators there are, since this might even change on some conditions) in the parent component due to Single Responsibility. Because I am also required to add some controls to the form dynamically I am using reactive forms.

Comment: @coconutwater44 Updated my answer :)

Comment: I have marked your answer as accepted since it solves the problem I described in the question, thank you! The problem does however occur again with either a) one more level of nesting (so the form is passed down one more level, e.g. App->ExtraContainer->FormContainer) or b) using custom FormControls implementing the `ControlValueAccessor` and `Validator` interfaces. Do you have any pointer on how I might fix this? Unfortunately as it stands right now my application requires I do both of that :D